# Cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy problem for plotting graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, pytorch

as mentioned in the title, I am facing the problem of

TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.

I found out that that need to be a .cpu() method to overcome the problem, but tried various ways and still unable to solve the problem

```py
def plot(val_loss,train_loss,typ):
    plt.title("{} after epoch: {}".format(typ,len(train_loss)))
    plt.xlabel("Epoch")
    plt.ylabel(typ)
    plt.plot(list(range(len(train_loss))),train_loss,color="r",label="Train "+typ)
    plt.plot(list(range(len(val_loss))),val_loss,color="b",label="Validation "+typ)
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(data_dir,typ+".png"))
    plt.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess during loss calculation, when you try to save the loss, instead of

```
train_loss.append(loss)
```

it should be

```
train_loss.append(loss.item())
```

item() returns the value of the tensor as a standard Python number, therefore, train_loss will be a list of numbers and you will be able to plot it.
You can read more about item() here
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.item.html

Comment: Sorry, that still not solve my problem, as I dont have train_loss.append(loss)

Comment: Is it possible if i email you the full code?

Comment: can you share your code snippet where you initialize and stack your train_loss? That would help to solve the problem. My email is anh.q.ng99@gmail.com

Comment: email sent, thank for your time

Comment: I compared the code you sent with the snippet in the question. Line 192, `out = torchvision.utils.make_grid(inputs)`, did you comment out this when you got the bug? The numpy() function was only used 3 times in the code so maybe the bug is caused in the imshow() function.

Comment: Nope, that code was already commented out before that

Comment: I email you the error

Comment: In line 88, epoch_acc is still a tensor; therefore, train_acc_gph and val_acc_gph are also lists of tensor, which caused the bug. To fix this, line 82 should be `running_corrects += torch.sum(preds.detach() == labels.data)` and line 92 and 94 should be `train_acc_gph.append(epoch_acc.item())` and `val_acc_gph.append(epoch_acc.item())` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the GPU (CUDA) you need to get the data from the GPU to the CPU, doing e.g. :

```
plt.plot(list(range(len(train_loss))),train_loss.cpu().detach().numpy(),color="r",label="Train "+typ)
```

Comment: sorry, still facing a problem of

Comment: plt.plot(list(range(len(train_loss))),train_loss.cpu().detach().numpy(),color="r",label="Train "+typ)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'cpu'

Comment: the `train_loss` is a list, not tensor, it doesn't have cpu, detach or numpy function. In the codesnip you post, I didn't see `.numpy()` was called anywhere, I guess the problem should come from the line where you run `.numpy()`